# Laravel custom pagination exception | Undefined property $pageName

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, pagination

Error message :

> Undefined property:
>   Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::$pageName

I am creating pagination from an array and following is the array.

```
$array =  [▼
  "A" => 1
  "B" => 2
  "C" => 3
  "D" => 4
  "E" => 5
]
```

And have the following code :

```
public function paginate($items, $perPage = 5, $page = null, $options = [])
{
  $page = $page ?: (Paginator::resolveCurrentPage() ?: 1);
  $items = $items instanceof Collection ? $items : Collection::make($items);
  return new LengthAwarePaginator($items->forPage($page, $perPage), $items->count(), $perPage, $page, $options);
}
```

and calling the above method like the following :

```
$data = $this->paginate($array);
return view('test', ['data' => $data]);
```

And in `test` view, I've the following to show pagination links:

```
<div> {{ $data->links() }}</div>
```

I've no idea what am I missing, I've checked quite a lot.

Comment: you can use the laravel's paginate function. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/pagination

Comment: @HassaanAli As you can see i am pagination an array so its a custom pagination and having that issue.

Comment: Do you have an idea which line triggers the exception ?

Comment: @NMC yeah its the `$data->links()` in the view.

Comment: I'm looking at the package and having trouble finding a configuration where that error is possible. Maybe clean and reget the package trough composer ?

Comment: Have a look at that : https://medium.com/@sam_ngu/laravel-how-to-paginate-collection-8cb4b281bc55 You can convert `collect()` or modify it for your needs

Comment: Unsure what $pageName actually is, but you can feed it to the Paginator via the options array. So just try to set it to some string and see where that gets you. `$options['pageName']` = 'whatever';